# Wireshark unable to load customized plugin

Tags: windows, wireshark, asn.1, wireshark-dissector

Steps followed:

1. Downloaded Wireshark(3.0.5) source, created build environment and build successfully without my custom dissector plugin.
2. Implemented custom plugin according to developer guide.
3. Build Wireshark with custom plugin, created xxx.dll for plugin then created installer using NSIS.
4. Custom Wireshark installer created and installed on system.
5. After installation while loading plugins, an error occurs "Couldn't load plugin 'xxx.dll :C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireshark\plugins\3.0\epan\xxx.dll':Specified module could not be found.
6. I verified the location where global plugins reside path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireshark\plugins\3.0\epan\xxx.dll" is there.

I'm unable to find root cause for the issue.  If anybody has an idea, please share.

a) Build on Windows 7 professional
b) 32 bit installer
c) Installed on windows 10, 7

Comment: This question is better suited to [Wireshark's forum](https://ask.wireshark.org). Stack  Overflow focuses on code.

Comment: I think you missed something. ;)  Besides the Wireshark Developer Guide, I'd recommend carefully reading the doc\README.plugins file.  It's possible the Developer Guide isn't up to date, and if that's found to be the case, then please file a bug report for it at https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/.

Comment: Thanks for advise i will post on wireshark forum